# Counting the number of times a character in string1 is found in string2?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a function which takes two strings and then returns the sum total of how many times every character in the first string is found in the second string under the condition that duplicate characters in the first are ignored.

e.g. `search_counter('aabbaa','a')` would mean a count of 1 since the the second string only has one `a` and no `b`s and we only want to search for `a` once despite there being four `a`s.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
def search_counter(search_string, searchme):
    count = 0
    for x in search_string:
        for y in searchme:
            if x == y:
                count = count + 1
    return count
```

The problem with my example is that there is no check to ignore duplicate characters in search_string.
So instead of getting `search_counter('aaa','a') = 1` I get `3`.

Comment: *"The problem with my example is that there is no check to ignore duplicate characters in search_string"* - so **add that**!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this (at least not without excessively over-complicating the code with individual "is less than 1?" counters for every letter in the alphabet that could be put in search_string) hence why I posted the question.

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor a tutorial service; please read [ask]

Comment: I'm not sure how you think my question or comment oversteps the bounds of the **How to Ask** section. I'm not even sure how you infer that I want you to code-write or be a tutorial service to me either - I asked an open-ended question with no expectation that responses should be solutions in code (not that I don't appreciate it). I would've been content with a hint or even just a point in the general direction of useful concepts e.g. **"Learn about sets."** Surely you can see how your first comment does not contribute to the discussion since its essentially akin to saying **"Then do it."**

Comment: *"I would've been content with a hint or even just a point in the general direction of useful concepts"* - if they are answers then, again, this isn't an appropriate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in search_string:
```

You can get a list of characters without duplicates by converting the string to a set.

```
for x in set(search_string):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate repetitions from a string by transforming it into a set:

```
>>> set("asdddd")
set(['a', 's', 'd'])
```

Preprocess your string this way, and the rest of the algorithm will remain the same (`set` objects are iterables, just like `strings`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use iteration to do this

```
def search_counter(string, search):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        count += string[i:].startswith(search)
    return count
```

Or this one-liner

```
search_counter = lambda string, search: sum([string[i:].startswith(search) for i in range(len(string))])
```